# Is it somehow possible to change the format of a telephone number being displayed?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, localization

On my Samsung Galaxy S phone a local telephone number is displayed in the format `999-999-999`.

Is it possible to change this format ?

Our local numbers are normally displayed as `99-999-99-99` , certainly the first two numbers are the area code.

Maybe is has to do with my language settings, because I used English as language.

Comment: What happens if you change your locale?

Comment: @Al Everett: Yes, the format changes. I have set my language now to English (UK) in stead of English (US) and now the numbers are formatted without hyphens (I prefer using English in stead of Dutch because of the references in sites like these: please press : settings - that option - this option . It's much easier to be able to just follow the text in stead of having to translate each and every guide line. However, I was still hoping for some setting to be able to set the format string myself.

Comment: Well, I'll add that as an answer. I don't believe there's a more direct method, but if you find one please be sure to add it as an answer.

Comment: did you succeed in your search for manually format the numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your language setting from "English (US)" to "English (UK)".