# Is it possible to change how Froyo hyphenates phone numbers?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-milestone, phone-app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it somehow possible to change the format of a telephone number being displayed ?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/is-it-somehow-possible-to-change-the-format-of-a-telephone-number-being-displayed)

In Brazil, phone numbers have two digits for the area code and eight for the phone number. Moreover, the carrier sends the caller ID with a leading zero, so that's how I store phone numbers. Example: 02155557777 for the Rio (21) number 5555-7777.

Before I updated from 2.1 to Froyo, numbers were presented with no hyphens. Now, the phone hyphenates them all. But it assumes a US standard, so it comes like 021-555-57777.

Moreover, when I'm dialing local (i.e. 8 digits), say, 5555-2222, it shows as 555-222-22.

Is there any way I can change that? Either positioning the hyphens correctly, or getting rid of the hyphens altogether?

Comment: Did you do an official OTA update?

Comment: Is your locale set to Brazil?

Comment: @Matthew: the update was not OTA but it was official. I downloaded it from: http://www.motorola.com/staticfiles/Support/GB-EN/froyo/milestonenotification.htm

Comment: @Al: No, it's to US English, as it was before. The one Portuguese locale available is not Brazil, but Portugal. Besides, I'd rather keep the UI in English.

Comment: Well, sadly, that's probably why it's formatting the numbers as it is. What happens if you use your own hyphens? How about some other character, like a dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the hyphening was a consequence of changing the locale from UK English (which is what the phone came configured with) to US English. Changed it back to UK English and the hyphens went away.

Comment: Be sure you mark this as the correct answer!