# Is it somehow possible to change MANUALLY the format of a telephone number?

Tags: contacts, phone-app

In this question [Is it somehow possible to change the format of a telephone number being displayed ?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/is-it-somehow-possible-to-change-the-format-of-a-telephone-number-being-displayed) @Edelcom asked to change the format of telephone numbers, but he could get his wanted format just by changing his language. By manually I mean that I want to set it up no matter the language such as the format I want isn't in any of the languages I speak.

By the way: my phone is a Samsung Galaxy i5510.

Comment: Not without rolling your own ROM I expect.

Comment: Why would you expect so? I don't think it would be "wrong" to be able to customize this.

Comment: Because, to date, this hasn't been available in any of the commercially-available versions of Android.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you mean expect as "wish"

Answer (score 1):

This is a function of your dialer and contact-saving/editing application. Various ROMs use various applications (be it AOSP Dialer, Motoblur, Sense, Touch Wiz, etc.).

You can install third-party dialers. I've never used it but [this dialer](https://market.android.com/details?id=intelgeen.rocketdial.trail) supposedly supports what you're asking for. I suggest you browse around the Market for third-party dialers.

Comment: I've downloaded it. I can't find how to achieve what I'm looking for in the settings. Could you please tell me where can I find this feature please?