# Changing the numbers format when entering phone numbers in the dialer possible?

Tags: keyboard, localization, phone-app, text-input

I'm using a Sony Live With Walkman. The Android 2.3 is in English, and I rather leave that way... But, I find kind awkward the mask input of numbers when I am typing.

[image: dialer]

Is there any way I can change that?

I would prefer something like 9999-9999, or at least no mask at all.

Comment: That is built into the dialer in the Sony's Android ROM and baked in. Try an alternative dialer!

Comment: Possibly related: [Is it somehow possible to change MANUALLY the format of a telephone number?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11022/is-it-somehow-possible-to-change-manually-the-format-of-a-telephone-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it may seen, there's no solution without relying on third-part softwares.

Instead, I (partially) solved it by changing the language for English UK, where the numbers format are without separators. Ex: 99999999.