# Customizing the formatting of phone numbers

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, localization

Mobile operators in Brazil have added a leading digit, but *only* for São Paulo numbers. Now, both landline numbers (in São Paulo and otherwise) and mobile numbers from other states have 8 digits, while São Paulo mobile numbers have 9 (in addition to the optional area code that's 2 digits).

I'd like 8-digit numbers to be formatted like 1234-5678 and 9-digit numbers formatted like 123-456-789. Is this possible?

I've read the answers to following questions and none of them anwers this question:

- [Is it somehow possible to change the format of a telephone number being displayed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/is-it-somehow-possible-to-change-the-format-of-a-telephone-number-being-displaye)
- [The Way Numbers Are Displayed/Broken Up](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25920/the-way-numbers-are-displayed-broken-up)

Answer (score 0):

What I will do with the same problem :

- export Google Gmail contacts as a CSV file from https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#contacts
- using [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to edit the file with some [REGEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
- importing contacts again

Answer (score 0):

I use [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/en/) to do tasks like this.  It will download contacts to the PC, where you can use the tool to edit the contacts and write them back.  But it's only one at a time.

I find it much easier to use this to tidy up all my contacts, periodically.

Screenshot of this feature from their website.  I am not associated with it any way, just been using it for forever.

[image]